# Code storage for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have never really used any type of product for code/project/solution storage.  I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions on the one that is suggested by Microsoft to use or what is used in environments with multiple developers.

Any answer that could point me in the right direction would be extremely helpful.

Comment: By "code storage" do you mean version control? Git is all the rage these days.

Comment: Is Git used for private storage or open source?  In my mind "version control" is just a type of "code storage".  :)  Is Git integrated into VS 2015?

Comment: Git is popular for both private and open projects. I think Microsoft provides support for Git in VS but I'm not sure how popular their implementation is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically two options used in development environments: Git and Subversion (SVN).

**Git** - Git is a Distributed version control systems (DVCS) meaning that the code is stored in multiple places(developers don't just check out the latest version of the code). I would say this seems to be one of the more popular and widely used version control platforms. In Git you download a copy of the code repository (known as "Cloning") onto your local computer. You then typically create a branch that will house the changes that you make to the code and then "commit and push" the code back up to the hosting repository where it is typically reviewed, merge conflicts resolved (if any), and then merged into the Master branch. Of course git is flexible and this is only one example of a typical "workflow" in Git. You can Google Git Workflows for a number of articles and examples.

Git Resources

- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)

**Subversion (SVN)** - SVN is a The main difference here is that your code is maintained in a central location and each developer must check-out the code to work on it. Only one developer can have the code checked out at a time (this prevents issues like merge conflicts that you have in Git). Things like branches also exist in Subversion, but to be honest I have not had much experience in working with them in SVN.

SVN Resources

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion
- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

Now that we got the basics of Git and SVN out of the way, we can talk to the Visual Studio component. In my opinion I would say go with either GitHub (http://github.com), Bitbucket (http://bitbucket.org), or Microsoft's online TFS implementation called "Visual Studio Team Services" (https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs). Any of these services will work with Visual Studio's built in version control system. The difference will be in the features you get such as free private repositories (get those with Visual Studio Team Services and Bitbucket), bug/issue tracking options, Wikis, etc.

Personally I would recommend either Visual Studio Online (VSO) or GitHub. VSO will give you free, private repositories but they don't really have good issue tracking options for their free accounts. GitHub's free accounts don't give you private repos, but they have some nice issue tracking features and wikis. In the context of Visual Studio though the interface and how you interact with your repository will be the same regardless of which you choose.

Comment: Did you just type all that...? Nice.